# Paste Unicode characters into IntelliJ source code editor in a string without converting to Unicode code point numbers

Tags: java, intellij-idea, unicode, unicode-escapes, code-editor

In the IntelliJ 2019.2 code editor, if I paste this entire line:

```
String abc = "AZ" ;
```

The [KIWIFRUIT character](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F95D/) stays intact. Good.

But if I start with this line:

```
String abc = "AZ";  // Before pasting
```

…and paste the single character  in between the `A` and the `Z` of the string, the KIWIFRUIT is replaced with the [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) representation of the character as a pair of high surrogate and low surrogate numbers: `\uD83E\uDD5D`.

```
String abc = "A\uD83E\uDD5DZ" ;
```

I understand that this pair of hex numbers is just an alternate way to represent the KIWIFRUIT character. But I would rather see the single character in my source code.

I have verified the `.java` is configured within IntelliJ to be UTF-8. And as I have shown, pasting the entire line results in the green emoji glyph being displayed within the code editor.

➥ Is there some way to turn off IntelliJ’s converting of high-numbered Unicode characters into a hex string?

Comment: I think this is a similar behaviour to if you paste a quote mark inside a string literal, it will escape it, whereas if you paste the line `String s = """;` then it won't escape it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Edit | Paste as Plain Text` (`Paste without Formatting` or `Past Simple` if you are using an older IDE version)

Mac: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

PC: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: It works in windows also by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Shift+V

Comment: In 2020.3 it is `Edit | Paste as Plain Text`